# Программа понимает нужное действие только из второго раза (язык C#)

Tags: c#

Не давно начал учится C#, захотел проверить свои знания и с огромным трудом додумался до вот такого кода (несколько дней назад начал учить):

```
Random rand = new Random();

int free;
free = rand.Next(1, 20);
string Cup = "Да";
string Cap = "Нет";

Console.WriteLine("Количество прожетых тобой лет: " + free);
if (Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()) == Cup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Я угадал");
}
if (Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()) == Cap)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Блин значит тебе " + free, " лет");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Но если я напечатаю ответ "да" программа поймёт из первого раза, а если ответ "нет" со второго, как это исправить?
**Не печатайте весь код (можно напечатать частичку, где используется то что вы хотите мне напечатать), я всё так научится хочу чему-то...**

Comment: Не надо читать ввод два раза, достаточно одного. Прочитанное сохранять в переменную и ее уже проверять, да это или нет.

Comment: Можно частичку кода при помощи которой можно использовать переменную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете считывать в переменную введенное значение, а потом сравнивать ее с "Да" и "Нет"

```
Console.WriteLine("Количество прожетых тобой лет: " + free);
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
if (answer == "Да")
... 
else if (answer == "Нет") 
...
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, можно пожалуйста частичку кода, в которой вы используете переменную?

Answer (score 1):

Вы написали `Console.ReadLine()` два раза - вот программа и читает строку из консоли два раза. Используйте переменные, их в язык не просто так добавили.

Кстати, нет никакого смысла преобразовывать строку в строку.

Comment: Здравствуйте, что означает "преобразовывать строку в строку" ? Как я и печатал, я начал учить несколько дней назад, и поэтому нечего не понимаю еще толком... 
И какую именно переменную использовать, и как? 
Можете напечатать частичку кода где это может использоваться )

Comment: @ЧеловекТайна вы делаете `Convert.ToString` для строки. В этом нет смысла. Но проблема не в этом.

Comment: @ЧеловекТайна переменную можете использовать любую, главное чтобы `Console.ReadLine()` только 1 раз вызывалась.

Comment: Извините, но как?

Comment: Как именно использовать переменную я имею ввиду. Можете напечатать небольшую часть кода которая нужна для того что-бы использовать переменную